# Where to find number of objects in space per altitude?

Tags: space

What I want is the sources to plot a graph such as the figure 3-3 on [this page](https://www.nap.edu/read/4765/chapter/6#65) but:

- Containing all objects whose size is greater than 10cm (including operational satellites)
- Raw numbers (the best would be a list containing for each observed object apogee and perigee of the described orbit)

Where can I find such a list?